# How to capture ffmpeg output in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg, system

I'm running a ffmpeg command to try to get the duration of a video file, the command is as follows...

```
system('ffmpeg -i C:\Users\example\Desktop\video9.mp4 -f ffmetadata')
```

When I run that line it outputs a lot of info to the rails console, including duration.  But how would I capture that info so I can split it and grab the data I need?  (I'm doing this inside a rails controller)

When I run something like this...

```
metadata = system('ffmpeg -i C:\Users\example\Desktop\video9.mp4 -f ffmetadata')
puts metadata
```

All it returns is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
output = `ffmpeg -i C:\\Users\\example\\Desktop\\video9.mp4 -f ffmetadata`
```

The problem is that `system` doesn't capture the output of the command being run. Instead, we use `%x[...]` or its equivalent using backticks, which captures the sub-shell's STDOUT.

If you need more control, look at [`Open3.capture3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3).

Comment: Was actually just in the process of doing this, usually this would be the right answer but I think what is happening is the output I am seeing is actually a stderr because with the ffmpeg command you need to specify a file at the end of the command, but I don't want to write to a file.  So if I can either capture the error text (which includes the info I need) or make te ffmpeg command somehow return a string instead of writing to a file I am good to go.

Comment: This got me partially there, and I think the problem was partially in the way I asked the question, so I'm accepting this, see my answer below for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

> ```
>   inspect_command = "ffmpeg -i " + file_location + " 2>&1 "
>   metadata = `#{inspect_command}`
> ```

Comment: The problem with using `2>&1` is it mixes STDERR and STDOUT. If `ffmpeg` never interweaves them then you're OK. Otherwise use `capture3` which works very nicely as a replacement. And, use `ffmpeg -i #{file_location} 2>&1` instead of `#{inspect_command}` because its cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to get is the video duration use [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) instead of ffmpeg. It returns the video metadata directly.